# .click doesn't work properly on jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

PHPstorm spoiled my files just now, so I have to rework everything. And for some  reason I can't get this working - click event just don't happen at all, neither with $("body"). It does work with $(document).on(...) though. 
 (script is inside head and script tags)

```
$("#cover").on('click',function(e) {
     $(e.target).removeClass("no");
     $(e.target).addClass("yes");
});


<body>
<div id="button"></div>
<div id="cover">
    <div class="rows" id="row1"></div>
    <div class="rows" id="row2"></div>
    <div class="rows" id="row3"></div>
    <div class="rows" id="row4"></div>
    <div class="rows" id="row5"></div>
    <div class="rows" id="row6"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: `$("body).click(function(){
alert("alert");
});` doesn't work now. wtf happened?

Comment: did ya check the chrome dev console for errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code is executed in the order in which it's found on the page.  So this:

```
$("#cover")
```

Needs to be executed *after* this is added to the page:

```
<div id="cover">
```

Otherwise that element won't be found by that selector, because it doesn't exist yet.

---

One approach is to move the JavaScript code to the bottom of the page.  (Or at least to after the target element exists.)  Another is to wrap it in the jQuery function which will attach it to the document's ready event:

```
$(function () {
    // add your code here
    // this will execute after the DOM is completely loaded
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I missed that moment.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this. It will execute once your DOM is ready.

```
$(function(){
   $("#cover").on('click',function(e) {
     $(e.target).removeClass("no");
     $(e.target).addClass("yes");
   });
});
```

Comment: Jeez, thanks.  Though I don't understand why it has to be written like that, and why it wasn't necessary last time I did it.

Comment: This runs once document is ready...it means every element on your page is loaded

Answer (score 0):

You could try reverting your changes in PHPStorm by right-clicking the folder, navigating to Local History -> Show History -> right click file(s)/folder(s) and select Revert Changes.

If that doesn't work do the following:

1. Move your javascript to the bottom of the page
2. Wrap the click with `$(document).ready(...)`
3. For debugging purposes do `console.log($("#cover"));` as your first line before binding a click event to see if jQuery object length is 1 or 0. If 1 the element is matched and found, if 0 then element doesn't exist or no match found.